# Android unable to connect to a Hotspot created by another Android Device

Tags: android, sockets, reflection, android-wifi

We are building an Android App which will let it connect to other android devices via a Socket Connection through a Wifi Hotspot created in the Server Android Device.

For most of the cases, this works perfectly. However for some cases, no matter how many times we try, a device is not able to connect to a WiFi Hotspot. This issue is not device specific. A device which is able to connect now, may not be able to connect at some other time.

While we were desperately looking for workarounds, we realized that if we Switch on and off the Hotspot in the connector, then it connects immediately to a WiFi Hotspot it was not able to connect previously.

Can anyone help us understand why is this happening? Also, is there anyway we can replicate this without switching off the WiFi Radio(switching on the Hotspot switches the Radio off)?